# What admin credentials are needed for AppSource submission testing

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, appsource

Regarding the AppSource submission, the docs state the following:

1. "You must provide at least two login credentials, one admin and one non-admin"
2. "For enterprise apps, apps where a subscription is required, or apps where there is an Office 365 tenant/domain dependency, you must provide a third account in the same domain that is not pre-configured for your app so that we can validate the first-run user experience."

For #1, our add-in does require external login and we will provide test credentials. However we don't have the concept of an "admin user" within the add-in. What exactly are we meant to provide for that?

For #2, our add-in will require that the user have an account with us (subscription?) what exactly do we need to provide? Another user of our system without access so it can be verified how that user experience is? A user will not be allowed to upgrade themselves but will be prompted to call our customer rep.

Comment: Customer service questions are off topic here. For assistance on Microsoft Commercial Marketplace, Azure Marketplace, AppSource and Certification issues, please sign-in to Marketplace Publisher Support at https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
 
 · Create a ticket in Partner Center
 · Browse Topics
 · Category: Commercial Marketplace
 · Topic: Certification
 · Sub-Topic: Office Add-in
 · Next step: Review solutions
provide issue details

Answer (score 0):

I've run into your first question: "You must provide at least two login credentials, one admin and one non-admin" as well with some confusion.

From what I can see this points to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/using-admin-roles. They define a teams admin by the role "Teams Service Administrator". This can be added to an account here https://admin.microsoft.com/adminportal/home, I'd recommend a guest account.

Hopefully this helps.